# Angular shared control not binding to observable from container component using async in template

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a shared component that is not binding to my observable data using the async pipe in the template.  I have confirmed that the data is present on init in the parent component of the shared control.  What am I missing?

ParentComponent

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col> 
    <ion-card *ngIf="popupname=='childcomponent'">  
        <ion-card-content>
          <app-childcomponent [mySelectEntityList$]="mySelectParticipants$"></app-childcomponent> 
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

ChildCompnent - HTML

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let participant of participants$ | async; let i = index" class="ion-text-center mo-no-padding">
  <ion-col>
    <ion-item>
      <my-select #moSelectComponent
        [prmMultiSelect]="mySelectMultiSelect" 
        [prmEntities$]="mySelectEntityList$" //I expect this to bind, but nothing is binding
        [prmInterfaceType]="myInterfaceType"
        (entitySelectionChange)="onMySelectChange($event,participant.userName)"
        ></my-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

ChildCompnent - TS

```
  @Input() public mySelectEntityList$: Observable<MoSelectEntity[]>;
//just to test if the data is actually coming in I did this in my ngOnInit and indeed the data is coming through:
      this.moSelectEntityList$.subscribe(val => console.log( ' the entity values passed in: ', val));
```

Note: I have validated that the Observable data (mySelectEntityList$) is being passed in by doing a subscribe on init and console logging the data just to test that it is coming in.  What I was doing before some refactoring is getting all the data for mySelectEntityList$ from within the ngOnInit on ChildComponent.  That works, however, it is not a good pattern I think and actually calls my api as many times as there are instances of the shared control on the page.  This is why I refactored to have the data passed in from the parent to the child to the shared component , since the mySelectEntityList$ data for the dropdown should be the same for all instances of the shared control.

SharedComponent

```
<ion-select
    [interfaceOptions]="{cssClass: 'setMaxHeight'}"
    [interface]="prmInterfaceType" 
    [multiple]="prmMultiSelect" 
    (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" 
    name="my-select-dropdown"
    ngDefaultControl>
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let entity of prmEntities$ | async" [value]="entity">
        {{entity.entityName}}
    </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

SharedComponent - TS

just to test I did this and nothing was logged to the console, meaning that the Observable is not being triggered??? But why given that I've used the async pipe on the html template:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    // throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  this.prmEntities$.subscribe(val => console.log( ' the entity values passed in: ', val));

}
```

Comment: can you give an example on stackblitz?

Comment: I think `mySelectParticipants` is of type` Subject` and already when you sync it doesn't even have the event

Comment: In ChildComponent `ts` it's `mySelectEntityList$`, whereas in ChildComponent `html` it's `moSelectEntityList$`

Comment: why you are not using it this way? 
[prmEntities]="moSelectEntityList$ | async"

Comment: @Siddhant that was a typo.  I fixed it.

Comment: @Chris I checked again and mySelectParticipants is indeed an observable.

Comment: @Babaei I tried that but same outcome.  I can switch it to what you suggest if that is a better syntax, but the way I have it should work too.

Comment: @Chris I have created a full stackblitz app to illustrate: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o5wjvf. I've simplified the scenario I described in this post as I've played around with it.  The issue in my stackblitz is that the child component is returning an empty array.  But I'm expecting it to get the data from the httpService class.

Comment: @mo_maat but you are not using httpService

Answer (score 0):

You coud try to add this "async" in:

```
<my-select #moSelectComponent
        [prmMultiSelect]="mySelectMultiSelect"

        [prmEntities$]="mySelectEntityList$ | async" 

        [prmInterfaceType]="myInterfaceType"
        (entitySelectionChange)="onMySelectChange($event,participant.userName)"
        ></my-select>
```

If that doesn't work, you could try this another one:

```
<app-childcomponent [mySelectEntityList$]="mySelectParticipants$ | async"
```

And, finally, you can try even the two changes together.

Comment: I've tried add async on all of them.  But still nothing displays on my component.  What did help was putting async on app-childcomponent (the last line you suggested).  As soon as I did that I saw my console logs display the expected data because I had added taps on my Observables in the parent component TS file.  So this gets me a bit further, but still the data is not binding in the shared component html.